# parse text file using awk and store in two variables

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to parse a file just like:

```
for NAME in `cat file.txt | grep name | awk '{print $2}'`
do
   echo " $NAME  "
   ......
done
```

file.txt content:

```
name John box 2
name Joe box 3
name May box 4
```

Then it will print:

```
John
Joe
May
```

But now I want to get box number in the meantime, I need to store name and box in two variables, how to do this?

Expected result:

```
echo "$NAME $BOX"
John 2
Joe 3
May 4
```

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues it tells you about, and also read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) as you probably have the wrong approach to your problem.

Comment: @EdMorton very useful website! good to know! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Awk ([or `cat`!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) here at all.

```sh
grep '^name' file.txt |
while read -r _ name _ box;
do
   echo " $name $box "
   ......
done
```

Or, if you just want to print those two fields and not do anything with those variables, simply

```sh
awk '/^name/ { print $2, $4 }' file.txt
```

See also [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

More fundamentally, you might want to modify your file format so that the labels don't have to be specified on every line (or if that's really useful, probably use a standard file format which allows for this sort of structure, like JSON or perhaps YAML).